# Web2Py POST Failure

Tags: python, post, web2py

Web2Py POST Failure

POSTing some dictionary data to Web2py.  Certain data POSTS consistently succeed, and certain data POSTS consistently fail.

This data consistently succeeds to POST:

```
data = {"batt chrg": {
            "dat": "-999%",
            "measurement": "percent",
            "unit": "electric",
            "entrytype": "subunitStatus"
            },
         "pv gen": {
             "dat": "-999 W",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "electric",
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus"
             }
         }
```

This data (longer dictionary) consistently Fails to POST:

```
data = {"download": {
            "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
            "dat": "9 Mbit/s",
            "measurement": "level",
            "unit": "comms"},
        "batt chrg": {
            "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
            "dat": "94.4%",
            "measurement": "percent",
            "unit": "electric"},
         "pv gen": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "543 W",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "electric"},
         "living space": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "72 F",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "hvac"},
         "ping": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "60 ms",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "comms"},
         "invert load": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "402 W",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "electric"},
         "humidity": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "45%",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "hvac"},
         "upload": {
             "entrytype": "subunitStatus",
             "dat": "8 Mbit/s",
             "measurement": "level",
             "unit": "comms"
             }
         }
```

Client-side python code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from datetime import datetime
import json

auth=HTTPBasicAuth('LoginID', 'Password')
unitid = '19700111'
uploaded = 'no'
data = {
    'unitid': unitid,
    'uploaded': uploaded,
    'time_stamp': str(datetime.now()),
    'data_list': json.dumps(data),
    }

rq = requests.post(
"https://XXXXX.pythonanywhere.com/XXX/default/api/packed_data.json",
data=data,
auth=auth,
headers={'Connection':'close'}
)
```

Here is the (standard) server-side Web2py code:

```
def api():  
    response.view = 'generic.'+request.extension
    def GET(*args,**vars):
        patterns = 'auto'
        parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
        if parser.status == 200:
            return dict(content=parser.response)
        else:
            raise HTTP(parser.status,parser.error)
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
    def PUT(table_name,record_id,**vars):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).update(**vars)
    def DELETE(table_name,record_id):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).delete()
    return dict(GET=GET, POST=POST, PUT=PUT, DELETE=DELETE)
```

The failure returns 'Response 200', but nothing is written to the database.

Comment: The code returns the result of `.validate_and_insert`. What exactly gets returned? Presumably there is a validation error.

Comment: Unfortunately, no errors / exceptions are raised.

Comment: Right, but it will return the result of the validation, which will show which fields have invalid data. It will be in the JSON body of the 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  There was nothing wrong with the code.  Web2Py sets a default length on string fields.  Defining the field length in db.py to a large number solved the problem:

```
db.define_table('packed_data',
                Field('unitid', 'string'),
                Field('uploaded', 'string'),
                Field('time_stamp', 'string'),
                Field('data_list', type='string', length=5000),
                redefine=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller returns the output of `db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)`. `.validate_and_insert` first runs the validators defined for each field and then does the insert only if there are no validation errors. If no record is inserted, this implies that there are validation errors.

Note, validation errors in this case do not automatically result in an exception or a non-200 HTTP response. Rather, the controller simply returns the output of `.validate_and_insert` (converted to JSON), which is a structure like:

```
{
  id: [ID of inserted record if successful or null otherwise],
  errors: {
    'field1': 'error message 1',
    'field2': 'error message 2',
    ...
  }
}
```

If you do not want a 200 response when there are validation errors, you can change the controller code to something like this:

```
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        result = db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
        if result.errors:
            raise HTTP(422, 'INVALID INPUT')
        return result
```

Alternatively, you can return the result with a 200 response and have your client code inspect the returned JSON to determine if there were any validation errors and take action accordingly.

In either case, you should be prepared to handle validation errors when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

In models.py for long long data you can try the Field type as 'text'

```
db.define_table('table_name',
            Field('column_name', 'text')
            )
```